# What address should I use for "localhost" in my Flutter app?

Tags: node.js, flutter, cors, xmlhttprequest, host

I was using the following code within my Flutter app and it was working with no problems, but today after I upgraded my Flutter, it doesn't work and gives me `XMLHttpRequest error`.

```
  Future<void> _authenticate(
      String email, String password, String urlSegment) async {
    final host = UniversalPlatform.isAndroid ? '10.0.2.2' : '127.0.0.1';
    final url = Uri.parse('http://$host:8000/api/$urlSegment');

    try {
      final http.Response response = await http.post(
        url,
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        body: json.encode(
          {
            'email': email,
            'password': password,
          },
        ),
      );
```

Does anything have been changed in new Flutter version? Should I change the following line of code that specifies my `host` address?

```
    final host = UniversalPlatform.isAndroid ? '10.0.2.2' : '127.0.0.1';
```

EDIT: I tried to add `cors` to my NodeJS backend server and this is my app.ts file as following:

```
import express, { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();
import config from "config";
import responseTime from "response-time";
import connect from "./utils/connect";
import logger from "./utils/logger";
import routes from "./routes";
import deserializeUser from "./middleware/deserializeUser";
import { restResponseTimeHistogram, startMetricsServer } from "./utils/metrics";
import swaggerDocs from "./utils/swagger";

const allowedOrigins = ['http://localhost:8000' , 'https://10.0.2.2:8000', 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'];

const options: cors.CorsOptions = {
  origin: allowedOrigins
};

const port = config.get<number>("port");

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());


app.use(cors(options));

app.use(deserializeUser);

app.use(
  responseTime((req: Request, res: Response, time: number) => {
    if (req?.route?.path) {
      restResponseTimeHistogram.observe(
        {
          method: req.method,
          route: req.route.path,
          status_code: res.statusCode,
        },
        time * 1000
      );
    }
  })
);

app.listen(port, async () => {
  logger.info(`App is running at http://localhost:${port}`);

  await connect();

  routes(app);

  startMetricsServer();

  swaggerDocs(app, port);
});
```

But still doesn't work and I get the same error!

Comment: So you are testing on web? And tertiary operator will pick `127.0.0.1` and browser will try to POST to 127.0.0.1:8000, where you are running some sort of server? The browser will complain unless the server at 127.0.0.1:8000 is producing the right CORS headers because that won't match the debug server that launched your app at 127.0.0.1:<randomPort> I doubt this has anything to do with the Flutter version, since this is a server CORS issue, unless something else changed (perhaps you were previously launching Chrome in unsafe ignore CORS mode)

Comment: @RichardHeap: Please check the `EDIT` part I added to my question. I also like to know if I should add something to my Flutter front end code too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've set the allowed origins to `:8000`, but that's the *backend* server's address. Instead, you need to set it to the Flutter debug server's address (and eventually to the web server where you host the production app, if that's not exactly the same as the backend server). (You can remove all the addresses ending in 8000.)

The problem is that the debug server picks a random port for each run. You can tell it to use a fixed port and then that becomes the port you need to include in your allowed origins.

Add `--web-hostname=localhost --web-port=9999` as command line parameters to where you run your `main.dart`, then add `localhost:9999` as an allowed origin.

(As a get-out-of-jail, also try `*` as an allowed origin.)

Finally, you should probably explicitly set the CORS allowed methods to the list of methods your server's API expects; probably OPTIONS, GET and POST.

Comment: I tried `const allowedOrigins = ['http://localhost' , 'https://10.0.2.2', 'http://127.0.0.1' , '*'];` but still doesn't work!

Comment: I am trying to find a way to add `--web-hostname=localhost --web-port=9999` to VSCODE settings because I don't use command line to run my app.

Comment: Chrome has useful diagnostics in Developer Tools on the Network tab. Filter by Fetch/XHR. You should see the options request and may see the response headers. (If not, use a packet capture like wireshark to see the request/response.)